# The type `&[u8]` cannot be indexed by `usize`?

Tags: rust

The following is the test code:

```
pub fn reverse_complement_seq_u8<T>(seq: T, len: usize) -> Vec<u8> 
    where T: std::ops::Index<usize, Output = u8>
{
    (0..len).rev().map(|i| match seq[i] {
            65 | 97  => 84, // 'A' | 'a' => 'T'
            84 | 116 => 65, // 'T' | 't' => 'A'
            71 | 103 => 67, // 'G' | 'g' => 'C'
            67 | 99  => 71, // 'C' | 'c' => 'G'
            n => n,
        } 
    ).collect()
}


fn main() {
    let seqs = "ACGATGCTACGA".as_bytes();//generated by another function
    let revcom_seq = reverse_complement_seq_u8(seqs, seqs.len());
    println!("{:?}", revcom_seq);
}
```

Because call `seqs.to_owend()` is expensive, so I just want to pass its reference to `reverse_complement_seq_u8`, however this cause the following errors:

```
error[E0277]: the type `&[u8]` cannot be indexed by `usize`
  --> src/main.rs:17:48
   |
17 |     let revcom_seq = reverse_complement_seq_u8(seqs, seqs.len());
   |                      ------------------------- ^^^^ `&[u8]` cannot be indexed by `usize`
   |                      |
   |                      required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = help: the trait `Index<usize>` is not implemented for `&[u8]`
   = help: the following other types implement trait `Index<Idx>`:
             [T; N]
             [T]
note: required by a bound in `reverse_complement_seq_u8`
```

Comment: Is your question what the error means, or why you get it, or ...?

Comment: BTW you can write `b'A'` instead of `65` to spare the comment `// 'A'`, etc.

Comment: Why did you write `seq: T ... where T: std::ops::Index<usize, Output = u8>` and not `seq: &[u8]`?

Comment: Becasue I can't guarantee that the `seqs` is always `[u8]`, but it alwasy can be indexed, such as [Seq](https://docs.rs/rust-htslib/latest/rust_htslib/bam/record/struct.Seq.html)

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that while the slice itself `[u8]` can be indexed, a reference to the slice `&[u8]` can't. Most of the time indexing a slice reference works because Rust automatically dereferences as needed, but when using generics you need to be more strict in what you tell the compiler.

One possible fix is to use `seq: &T` in the arguments so that `T` will be `[u8]` which can be indexed. This requires an extra `+ ?Sized` bound, otherwise the compiler adds an implicit `Sized` bound which slices don't implement:

```rust
pub fn reverse_complement_seq_u8<T>(seq: &T, len: usize) -> Vec<u8>
where
    T: std::ops::Index<usize, Output = u8> + ?Sized,
{
    (0..len)
        .rev()
        .map(|i| match seq[i] {
            65 | 97 => 84,  // 'A' | 'a' => 'T'
            84 | 116 => 65, // 'T' | 't' => 'A'
            71 | 103 => 67, // 'G' | 'g' => 'C'
            67 | 99 => 71,  // 'C' | 'c' => 'G'
            n => n,
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let seqs = "ACGATGCTACGA".as_bytes(); //generated by another function
    let revcom_seq = reverse_complement_seq_u8(seqs, seqs.len());
    println!("{:?}", revcom_seq);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7b07876cc6e4bb791222ea40cc8f6747)

Another option that will also work with boxed slices is to specify that `T` must deref to some indexable type:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
pub fn reverse_complement_seq_u8<T, U>(seq: T, len: usize) -> Vec<u8>
where
    T: Deref<Target = U>,
    U: std::ops::Index<usize, Output = u8> + ?Sized,
{
    (0..len)
        .rev()
        .map(|i| match seq[i] {
            65 | 97 => 84,  // 'A' | 'a' => 'T'
            84 | 116 => 65, // 'T' | 't' => 'A'
            71 | 103 => 67, // 'G' | 'g' => 'C'
            67 | 99 => 71,  // 'C' | 'c' => 'G'
            n => n,
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let seqs = "ACGATGCTACGA".as_bytes(); //generated by another function
    let revcom_seq = reverse_complement_seq_u8(seqs, seqs.len());
    println!("{:?}", revcom_seq);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e09364ecf21e0f24da2ddff15aaccb87)

Answer (score 1):

As [Jmb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397009/jmb) showed, you can make the constraint "type that is indexable by `usize`" work.

Depending on how you'll be using the function, or rather, what traits the values implement that you plan to use it with, an iterator approach may be useful as well, though.

Rather than iterating over a list of numbers to index `seq` with, you can accept an iterator of `u8`s directly:

```rust
pub fn reverse_complement_seq_u8<'a, T>(seq: T, len: usize) -> Vec<u8>
where
    T: std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator<Item = &'a u8> + std::iter::ExactSizeIterator,
{
    seq.take(len)
        .rev()
        .map(|val| match *val {
            65 | 97 => 84,  // 'A' | 'a' => 'T'
            84 | 116 => 65, // 'T' | 't' => 'A'
            71 | 103 => 67, // 'G' | 'g' => 'C'
            67 | 99 => 71,  // 'C' | 'c' => 'G'
            n => n,
        })
        .collect()
}

fn main() {
    let seqs = "ACGATGCTACGA".as_bytes(); //generated by another function
    let revcom_seq = reverse_complement_seq_u8(seqs.iter(), seqs.len());
    println!("{:?}", revcom_seq);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c918dcae4b885a73a82d889dbb2c99cf)

You could then also have your function return the iterator without `collect`ing, making it suitable to chain with additional iterator adapters.